# How to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Apple's Accelerator code?

Tags: ios, ipad, signal-processing, exc-bad-access, accelerate-framework

On sporadic occasions I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEV) in one of Apple's Accelerator framework methods, vDSP_fft2d_zip.  The crash report gave the following for Thread 10.  Again, most of the time this works like a champ. Any ideas on how to find the cause and fix it?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x412f2740
Triggered by Thread:  10
. . .

Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libvDSP.dylib                   0x2ddfcdb4 ___lldb_unnamed_function431$$libvDSP.dylib + 68
1   libvDSP.dylib                   0x2ddfab66 ___lldb_unnamed_function427$$libvDSP.dylib + 562
2   libvDSP.dylib                   0x2ddfa8ee vDSP_fft2d_zop + 434
3   libvDSP.dylib                   0x2ddfa732 vDSP_fft2d_zip + 18
4   ASSIST for iPad                 0x000ac32e -[Processor setupFilterForBubbleSizeMM:rectWidth:rectImageWidth:dataFilled:dataUnfilled:] (Processor.mm:813)
5   ASSIST for iPad                 0x000af4d2 -[Processor runConvolutionProcessOnImage:aveImage:] (Processor.mm:1835)
6   ASSIST for iPad                 0x000ac5f6 -[Processor processAnswers] (Processor.mm:869)
7   ASSIST for iPad                 0x000ae9cc -[Processor process] (Processor.mm:1644)
8   ASSIST for iPad                 0x000d7744 -[ReallTimeScanner processImage:] (ReallTimeScanner.mm:1046)
9   Foundation                      0x2f296c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x396b6c1a _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x396b6b8a _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x396b4c8c thread_start + 4
```

The relevant code looks like this:

```
#define FFT_SIZE 512
#define FFT_POWER 9

dataFilledIn->imagp=(float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);
dataFilledIn->realp=(float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);
dataUnfilledIn->imagp=(float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);
dataUnfilledIn->realp=(float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);

memset(dataFilledIn->imagp, 0, sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);
memset(dataFilledIn->realp, 0, sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);
memset(dataUnfilledIn->imagp, 0, sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);
memset(dataUnfilledIn->realp, 0, sizeof(float)*FFT_SIZE*FFT_SIZE);


for(float y=0; y<FFT_SIZE; y+=0.25)
{
    for(float x=0; x<FFT_SIZE; x+=0.25)
    {
        dataFilledIn->realp[(int)y*FFT_SIZE+(int)x] += 0.0625;
        dataUnfilledIn->realp[(int)y*FFT_SIZE+(int)x] -= 0.0625;
    }
}

vDSP_fft2d_zip(setup, dataFilledIn, 1, 0, FFT_POWER, FFT_POWER, kFFTDirection_Forward);
```

Comment: Since this looks to be in Apple's code, it may be a case where you should submit a Technical Support Incident (TSI) for help from Apple directly: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/

Comment: Should I be able to reproduce an error in order to submit a TSI?  It's very sporadic.

Comment: Provided you have a project with data that can crash within a period of time you should be OK.  It doesn't have to crash every time but you should be able to have the crash occur when Apple are checking through the project. Apple encourages you to submit a TSI for "if you cannot fix a bug" but make sure you read through the submission guidelines to make the most of the Apple Engineer's time.

Comment: The problem here turns out to be that the setup structure wasn’t initialized properly (according to the OP), but for this sort of thing it usually makes more sense to just “Report a Bug” rather than use a TSI; a DT engineer is unlikely to be able to give you much help with this sort of thing, whereas a bug report will be seen pretty quickly by the team that owns the component in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here: Be sure that the very first parameter sent in (type FFTSetup) to vDSP_fft2d_zip() is initialized correctly, and you should use this call

```
vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(setup);
```

to clean it up.  I was initializing the setup var properly, like this

```
setup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(FFT_POWER, kFFTRadix2);
```

and then cleaning it up, but then was not initializing it again before subsequent calls to vDSP_fft2d_zip().  Unfortunately it only rarely caused a crash, which made it seem like the frequent calls to vDSP_fft2d_zip(setup, . . .) were working when they weren't.  The crashes were sporadic making the real cause hard to trace.

Comment: I should note that if you're repeatedly creating and destroying setups, You're Doing It Wrong™.  Creating setups is quite expensive; you want to create a single setup just once, and re-use it for multiple calls to `vDSP_fft2d_zip` before destroying it.

Comment: I'm creating the setup only once.

Answer (score 0):

There are some articles in [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) may help you:

1. [Objectively Speaking: A Crash Course in Objective C for iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21320/objectively-speaking-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-ios6)
2. [Objectively Speaking 2: A Crash Course in Objective C for iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31814/objectively-speaking-2-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-for-ios-6)

Comment: Danny, I'll look those over and see if they shed any light.  The bug is obviously in Apple's code so I'm skeptical that further knowledge of crash reports will do more than continue to point in that direction.  But it may be that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Danny, those aren't even related to crash reports.  I think you meant something like this by Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs